# Browser script to automatically copy a "locked" file from a user's system (Windows)

Tags: windows, language-agnostic, automation, backup

For an automated web-backup solution we're thinking of, how can we access and copy a "locked" file from a user's system onto our webserver? This is of course with the user's permissions.

Just seeking code that demonstrate this.

Added: I know where the file is located, I do NOT want to prompt the user to select the file everytime. It should be that he accesses the website and the site automatically backups the file for him (a first time setup is fine)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use Java applets: http://www.captain.at/programming/java/

Comment: Interesting... nice simple example. Karl - do you think this applet could be modified to do so automatically whenever the user visits the page, rather than prompting them for permission?

Comment: :)... sigh... there ARE genuine needs for this as well! Perhaps I should think of a downloadable/installed program...

Comment: I do believe its possible to do what you are thinking without asking the user about it.

Answer (score 1):

If this is a web app, I sure hope what you want to do isn't actually possible. Imagine the security implications of that.

Comment: I can understand that - so there can be a setup involved of a "control" or something similar...